# BootCKCL.etl file size & Session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" stopped due to the following error: 0xC0000188

Tags: windows-8, boot, performance, logging, analysis

I have a few regular / re-occurring errors in my event viewer which seem to be linked to logging upon boot and shutdown. I am running Windows 8 x64 professional.

> Event ID 4:
>
> The maximum file size for session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" has been reached. As a result, events might be lost (not logged) to file "C:\WINDOWS\system32\WDI\LogFiles\BootCKCL.etl". The maximum files size is currently set to 104857600 bytes.
>
> Event ID 3:
>
> Session "Circular Kernel Context Logger" stopped due to the following error: 0xC0000188

I have tried renaming the BootCKCL.etl file and restarting, but a new one is created which is the same file size. The current file size is 102Mb

I also see this error but I am unsure if it related:

> Custom dynamic link libraries are being loaded for every application. The system administrator should review the list of libraries to ensure they are related to trusted applications. Please visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571 for more information.

The support article didnt really provide much help.

Is this a problem with booting / shutting down, or is it an issue with logging and the file sizes?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I opened up the BootCKCL.etl file in Windows Performance Analyzer, and it gave me a warning:

> Performance Analyzer noticed that 0 events and 13 buffers were lost in this trace.
>
> This is usually created by insufficient bandwidth for ETW logging. Please try increasing the minimum and maximum number of buffers and / or the buffer size. Doubling these values would be a good first attempt. Please note, though, that this action increases the amount of memory reserved for ETW buffers, increasing memory pressure on your scenario. See "xperf -help start" for the associated command line operations.
>
> Windows Performance analyzer might not be able to provide reliable data in this situation.
>
> Would you like to continue analyzing this trace?

Also, when I try to open Performance monitor I get this error:

> Unable to add these counters:
>
> \Memory\Available MBytes
>
> \Memory\% committed bytes in use
>
> \Memory\cache faults/sec
>
> \Physical Disk(*)\% idle time
>
> \Physical Disk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue length
>
> \Network interface(*)\bytes total/sec

Are all these errors with logging linked?

I have a boot trace etl file and performance monitor logs if anyone needs to see them?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

0xC0000188 means log is full:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xC0000188
# for hex 0xc0000188 / decimal -1073741432
  STATUS_LOG_FILE_FULL                                           ntstatus.h
# Log file space is insufficient to support this operation.
# 1 matches found for "0xC0000188"
```

Open regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\Circular Kernel Context Logger` and increase the the value `MaxFileSize` to 200.

Comment: hi thank you, I have carried out your suggestion but the error still persists :-(

Comment: can anyone else please help with these issues, they are driving me insane

Comment: can you make a normal boot trace? http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252 Maybe I can see issues and fixing them also fixes your issue.

Comment: is it just the *.etl file that you require? its 2Gb in size! If you can let me know I will upload it and send you the link.

Comment: compress the ETL as 7z and upload it to skydrive/dropbox/google drive and post a link here

Comment: Here you go https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzUKz7d908nTjM3RW9EUjdQU0E/edit?usp=sharing    - let me know if you have trouble accessing it

Comment: your boot is a disaster with a fast SSD like the 840 Pro. Can you post some AS SSD Benchmark (http://www.alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9) pictures? I see the SSD is so busy and this should not happen.

Comment: thanks again for your help.......I've used that benchmark before! Off the top of my head, the last time I ran the benchmark the overall score was over 1000. However, I will run it again when I get home from work and post the pictures for you.

Comment: Hi again magicandre. Here is the link to my SSD benchmarking image:  http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y164/jpmad4it/ssd.jpg

Comment: the sequential write is a bit slow, the rest seams to be ok: http://www.servethehome.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Samsung-840-Pro-256GB-SSD-AS-SSD-Benchmark.png Try to update the Intel AHCI driver or try the Microsoft AHCI driver. Does this improve performance? Have you tried to make a complete backup of the System, set the SSD back to the factory state and restore the image? This restore to factory state (use Samsungs SSD tool) improve performance.

Comment: if I do this, is it likely to fix the issues that I mentioned in my first post i.e. the errors that I am receiving in the event log and performance monitor?

Comment: try it out and look if it improves performance. If Windows now boots faster, you should have a smaller BootCKCL.etl.

Comment: I have the latest version of Intel Rapid Storage Technology RAID Driver - is this the same as the AHCI driver?  Is the BootCKCL.etl file so large due to the amount of start-up items? If so, if I restore the factory state of the SSD and then restore my windows image, will the problem with the BootCKCL.etl file just come back?

Comment: try the MS driver. I see you use a Marvell RAID, so you should not need an Intel RAID driver. Make a complete system image before changing anything.

Comment: I have my operating system on the SSD which is on the Intel controller and then 4x500GB HDD's in a RAID0 on the Marvell controller. Do I still not need the Intel driver?

Comment: I don't think you need the Intel driver.